# Swagger - TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Invalid name

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi

Swagger - Tried to Add Header from Componenet

```yaml
paths:
  '/customer':
        post:
          tags:
            - Customer
          summary: Create Customer
          description: Create Customer
          operationId: createCustomer
          parameters:
            - in: header
              name: operationId
              description: Content Type
              required: true
              schema:
                type: string
                example: createCustomer
            - $ref: '#/components/parameters/clientId'     
            - $ref: '#/components/parameters/tenantId'     
            - $ref: '#/components/parameters/tenantUri'     
            - $ref: '#/components/parameters/tenantDbname'     
            - $ref: '#/components/parameters/tenantSalt'     
            - $ref: '#/components/parameters/transactionFlag'     
            - $ref: '#/components/parameters/errorFlag'     
            - $ref: '#/components/parameters/enterpriseId'     
          requestBody:
              $ref: '#/components/requestBodies/createCustomer'      
          responses:
           '200':
              $ref: '#/components/responses/postsuccess'
           '400':
              $ref: '#/components/responses/postfailed' 
components:
  parameters:
     clientId:
      name: Client Id
      in: header
      description: Client Id
      schema:
      type: string
      example: "ABCD"
  tenantId:
     name: tenantId
     in: header
     description: "ABCD"
     schema:
      type: string
      example: "ABCD"
```

Comment: Can you please also post all referenced components? Use the `{}` button to format text as code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of *name: Client Id* , Please try with *name: ClientId* or *name: Client_Id*. I mean, It should be a single word.